# How to secure inputs in laravel 5.4

Tags: php, laravel

I have been searching on the internet about this but I couldn't find the exact solution to this.

I thought that laravel already handles the validation when data are saved into the database. But then, when I checked the data on the database, I can see records that accepts html tags like `<body>` etc. of course, I cannot display this on the browser because it will ruin my website.

Here is how I save the data using the request on my Controller post.

```
public function  submitTask(Request $request)
{
    Task::create([
     'task_title' => $request->title
    ]);
}
```

The name of my model is Task.

I want to secure my data from **XXS and other sql injection**.

How should I do this? many thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That is the way it was designed. You are not supposed to escape your data before saving it to the database. There, it's inoffensive. You are supposed to escape your data once it's output. As presentation logic, that's a responsibility of the View, and as such, in Laravel, you do it in Blade. Before 5.0, you had to use triple curly braces `{{{ }}}`, but now it's on by default on `{{ }}`.

You can read more about this [here](https://lukeplant.me.uk/blog/posts/why-escape-on-input-is-a-bad-idea/)

Comment: This means that all of the data should be put inside the three {{{ ?

Comment: Right, all the data you injected into the View from the Controller. Though since 5.0 you can use only two curly braces, it escapes the data by default.

Comment: Everything works fine but when I added data into the title section, it returns an error `Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '<' (` on this code `@section('title', {{ $data->title }})`

Comment: Try this: `@section("title") {{ $data->title }} @endsection`

Comment: Glad I could help. If you have more doubts, go [here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/blade). You'll definitely find what you're looking for.